# Firefox console Error: attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope

Tags: javascript, firefox, console

I have the below error appearing in my Firefox error console.  It shows lots of times, every time I refresh the page.

> Error: attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope Source
>   File: chrome://firebug/content/net/httpActivityObserver.js Line: 136

This seems to appear on every tab and even if I delete all code from the page this still happens.  I therefore assume this is a firefox bug and not something in my own code.  I cannot debug my own scripts due to this.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What version of Firefox and Firebug are you running? Have you tried disabling all your add-ons (except for Firebug)?

Comment: version 10.0.2 firefox and 1.9.1 firebuf, I will try and disable them now.  thanks.

Comment: ive disabled the add ons and the error messages have gone.  So its an add - on.   How will I know which it is?

Comment: Re-enable them one at a time and check for the error to occur again.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a Firefox issue.

The code I've written below works perfectly in Chrome, but in Firefox (12) it doesn't work at all; with the same error as described in the question.

NOTE: I don't have Firebug installed. I used the console in Tools/Web Developer.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        document.write("CORS test");
        function createCORSRequest(method, url){
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
                xhr.open(method, url, true);
            } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
                xhr = new XDomainRequest();
                xhr.open(method, url);
            } else {
                xhr = null;
            }
            return xhr;
        }

        var request = createCORSRequest("GET", "http://a.localhost:25565/");

        function doneLoading(rq)
        {
            document.write(rq.responseText);
        }

        if (request){
            document.write("<br />Requested..<br /><br />");
            console.log(request);
            request.onload = function() { doneLoading(request) } 
// THE ERROR POINTS TO THE ABOVE LINE
            request.send();
        }
        else {
            document.write("<br />No request!");
        }

    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is listed as a firebug-issue. http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4690

Answer (score 0):

A simple quit and restart of the browser worked for me using Firefox 12 (OS X 10.6.8). Was getting this: http://cl.ly/3P3E2U1p050s351i3C2W, after restart all errors were gone.